# Are residuals in time series decomposition normally distributed?

Tags: time-series

Does residuals in time series decomposition have to be normally distributed ?

Comment: Could you please give use more details ? What residuals are you talking about ?

Comment: When we do STL decomposition, we get trend seasonality and residue. So those residues have to be normally distributed?